# Why is $\lim_{x\to0+}x\cot (x)=1$?

Tags: calculus, limits, intuition

Why is $\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}x\cot (x)=1$?

Since both $x$ and $\cot (x)$ are continuous at zero and both equal to zero at $x=0$ why is the limit of both of them $1$?

i.e why isn't it:  $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+}x\cot (x)=0\cdot 0 = 0$?

PS: I know how to find the limit:  $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}x\cot x=\lim_{x\to0}\frac {x\cos (x)} {\sin (x)}=\lim_{x\to 0} \cos (x) = 1$ and it's the same with LHR too but I just find it strange since both of them are supposed to be $0$.

Comment: Actually, $\cot$ is not continuous at $0$. We have $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\cot x = -\lim_{x\to 0^+}\cot x = \infty$

Comment: @fonini Did you mean $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+}\cot x = -\lim\limits_{x\to 0^{\color{red}-}}\cot x$?

Comment: Your "PS" answer is OK.

Comment: yes, of course, sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cotangent is the reciprocal (the multiplicative inverse) of the tangent, that is $1/ \tan x$. The tangent is $0$ at $0$ so its reciprocal has a pole at $0$.

It is important to note that while the cotangent is $(\tan x)^{-1}$ this is not the same as $\tan^{-1} (x)$, the inverse function (the functional inverse) of the tangent also called arcus tangent. This would be $0$ at $0$.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**

$\cot(0)$ isn't equal to $0$, in fact $\cot$ isn't continuous at $x=0$.

Comment: Ohh right.. I mixed it up with an upside down $\tan x$...